# ActiveX Legacy Application IE11 End of Life

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, activex, ie-compatibility-mode

We have an application that uses ActiveX. With Microsoft's recent announcement that they will remove IE11 via a Windows update in June 2022, does anyone know of a standalone browser that will work with ActiveX permanently, regardless of Windows updates?

The application works in Edge (after adding it to IE mode, allowing unsecured content, and allowing pop-ups), but we fear that one day a Windows update will break this. The application currently works in IE11 in compatibility mode on Windows 10 and without compatibility mode  in IE11 on Windows 7.

Editing the code of the application is not an option. We are really looking for a simple browser that does not receive updates and that does support ActiveX.

I am not familiar with ActiveX at all really, so I'm not sure how it works, but from the research I've done, it looks like IE and Edge are the only options apart from the IE Tab extension in Chrome and the ff-activex-host plugin for Firefox which both rely on IE being installed (to my knowledge).

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveX is a Microsoft-specific framework, and it is only supported in `IE browser` or `Edge IE Mode`. I think you can continue to use Edge IE mode, and it will be supported for a long time in the future (at least 2029). For more Q&A, you could refer to this article: [Internet Explorer 11 desktop app retirement FAQ](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549).

Otherwise, I think you have to find something to replace ActiveX.